# Roll up summary field value is not detected in trigger old and trigger new

Tags: apex, trigger, roll-up-summary

Roll up summary field value is not detected in trigger old and trigger new

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Rollup Summary fields are calculated after triggers. If you need something done with this information, you need asynchronous code:

```
public class W {
    @future static void doSomething(Set<Id> recordIds) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

---

```
trigger X on Y (after insert, after update) {
    if(!System.isFuture() && !System.isBatch()) {
        W.doSomething(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
    }
}
```

Feel free to customize this logic if you only need to do stuff based on some criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) instead of standard rollups if you want the changes to be trigger-able. Because `Apex` is used to make the change, the values should be populated when you need them.